# Get-Disk values are different in powershell and in sql database

Tags: sql, powershell

Hi i'm completely new to this ,i want to store capacity in particular format. Mycode showing correct format but in **SQL** database its value is getting changed to default.

My code:

```
$SSDCapacity= Get-Disk | select Size
foreach($size in $SSDCapacity)
{
    $variable = $size.Size.ToString()
}
$result = $variable.SubString(0,3)
$result
```

Above code shows output as **512 in powershell**.

But when i store it in database its showing in default form **@{Size=512110190590}**

I have a insert query for SQL Part

```
$InsertQuery="INSERT INTO [$($Database)].[dbo].[$($name)]
           ([ComputerName],[Model],[SSDCapacity])
     VALUES('$ComputerNameValue','$ModelValue','$result')
"
```

then i'm just calling above query for insert

```
#Insert into Table
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $InsertQuery  
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter  
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd   
#Creating Dataset  
$Datatable = New-Object "System.Data.Datatable"
$result = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.Close()
```

So how can i store in format powershell shows.

I might be missing out some silly things here.
Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Without showing the code which actually inserts the data into the database we can't help you.

Comment: "But when i store it in database" - you forgot to post the code that stores it in a database :)

Comment: Btw `$variable.SubString(0,3)` is a really bad idea, you probably want to do `$result = [int]($variable/1GB)` instead

Comment: @Shubhkumar You're using `$SSDCapacity` in the insert query, but the value you want to insert is stored in `$variable` :)

Comment: makes probably more sense to calculate the size instead off cutting of the string. you get bytes and probably you want GB so just do $variable / 1GB.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, i made those changes but same output

Comment: @Toni, thanks for reply but i want first 3 characters from bytes.

Comment: You should take note of to the commenters about taking the first 3 characters of the string representing the disk size - at the moment you'll get ```"512"``` regardless of whether your disk size is really ```512``` bytes, ```512110190590``` bytes or ```5120000000000000000000``` bytes. If you want to know how many gigabytes there are, do what @MathiasR.Jessen suggests above and use ```$result = [int]($variable/1GB)```, or maybe ```[int]($variable / [math]::pow([long]10, 9))``` if you want it in "Marketing Gigabytes" (i.e. 10^9 bytes per gigabyte)

Comment: And your data suggests your actual SQL looks more like ```VALUES('$ComputerNameValue','$ModelValue','$size')``` - i.e. using ```$size``` rather than ```$result``` in your ```INSERT``` query so you get the string representation of the ```$size``` ***object*** - see this for an example: ```$x = [pscustomobject] @{"Size"=512110190590}; write-host "$x"``` -> ```"@{Size=512110190590}"```. Check the code you're actually running in your script matches your sample above...

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in one line using DBATOOLS

```
Install-Module dbatools -Scope CurrentUser #only once

Get-DbaDiskSpace|select ComputerName, Name, Capacity, Free|Write-DbaDataTable -SqlInstance $sql -Database TEMPDB -Table disk -AutoCreateTable
```